# Unexpected AVR prescaling weird problem

Tags: avr

I have problem setting the correct prescaler for a clock using an external 32k crystal. Not really a problem, but rather an unknown.

The correct prescaler for it should be 1/128

```
//32.768k/128=256; 256/256=1 second!!
```

But it's 1 second too slow, the right one seems to be 1/64, but why?

Here is the code:

```
ASSR |=1<<AS2;
TCNT2=0; 
TCCR2B= ((1<< CS22) ); // 1/64
while (ASSR& ( (1<<TCN2UB) | (1<<TCR2BUB) ) );
TIMSK2 |= 1<< TOIE2;
sei();
//32.768k/128=256; 256/256=1 second!!


ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect){ number++; }
```

Comment: How are you measuring the divided frequency?

Comment: @Tom Carpenter I just eyeball it. I can tell a 1 second from a 2 second.

Comment: But what are you eyeballing?! Your code has no output.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter Clearly the "number" is connected to a display, and I also have tested this code with a blinking LED.

Comment: "clearly". My mass surveillance network doesn't appear to be working at the moment though. In all seriousness though, the reason I was asking is there are many people who try to measure a clock with a toggling LED not realising that if you toggle an LED say every second, it will blink at 0.5Hz not 1Hz. That's why I am trying to find out what you are measuring with...

Comment: You also haven't specified what MCU you are using (e.g. ATMega328P?). "AVR" is a CPU inside a microcontroller. The times are separate peripherals.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter I maybe dumb, but I know how a blinking led works.  Here is the code, to be exact. ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect){ PORTB ^= 1 << 5; }  It blinks the LED @ 0.25 hz, or it takes about 2 seconds to toggle that LED.

Comment: "I maybe dumb" - I didn't say you were dumb. But you did ask for assistance. In order to get assistance you need to actually explain the problem you are having, and steps you are taking. Even the best of us can make a systematic error now and then. But anyway, you clearly don't want my help, so good luck to you.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter I am very sorry if I have offended you in anyway. It was never meant to be, but from you previous comment, you were really implying that I am too dumb to realized how to use a LED to measure a frequency, especially at low frequency like 1hz, and technically, the specific MCU is not important at all because timer is the same thing across many AVR MCUs.